# Rust vector of struct instances with (non-circular) references to each other

Tags: rust, reference, reference-counting

I'd like to create a vector of `TestStruct`. `TestStruct` has an optional reference to another `TestStruct` instance. No `TestStruct` will ever reference itself, nor will there be circular references with the intended use. Multiple `other`s can reference the same `TestStruct`. The `TestStruct` instances do not need to mutate.

Is it possible to express this using references, or do I need `Rc` and `Weak`?

```
struct TestStruct<'a>
{
    other: Option<&'a TestStruct<'a>>
}

fn testFn()
{
    let mut events = vec![TestStruct{other: None}];
    events.push(TestStruct{other: Some(&events[0])});
}
```

yields:

```
error[E0502]: cannot borrow `events` as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable
 --> src\test.rs:9:5
  |
9 |     events.push(TestStruct{other: Some(&events[0])});
  |     ^^^^^^^----^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^------^^^^^^
  |     |      |                            |
  |     |      |                            immutable borrow occurs here
  |     |      immutable borrow later used by call
  |     mutable borrow occurs here
```

Can I make it work for example by creating a vector of `Box<TestStruct>` instead? Or will a reference to a TestStruct whose box is in the vector implicitly borrow the vector as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we accept some restrictions,

- not actually using a `Vec`
- not being able to move the structure after creating it

then this can be done with [`typed_arena::Arena`](https://docs.rs/typed-arena/2.0.1/typed_arena/struct.Arena.html):

```rust
// [dependencies]
// typed-arena = "2.0.1"
use typed_arena::Arena;

struct TestStruct<'a> {
    other: Option<&'a TestStruct<'a>>,
}

pub fn test_fn() {
    let events = Arena::new();
    let first = &*events.alloc(TestStruct { other: None });
    let second = &*events.alloc(TestStruct { other: Some(first) });
}
```

The key difference in what `Arena` offers is that `Arena::alloc()` takes `&self` — indicating that only a *shared* reference to the arena is required to allocate (add the element). Rust's mutability rules therefore tell us that we can keep using the returned reference even as we `alloc()` more, whereas `Vec::push()` invalidates all existing references (as it must, since the vector's items might be moved into reallocated memory to grow the vector).

However, all those references are still borrows of the arena. Thus, the arena is effectively pinned — you cannot, for example, take this whole data structure and *return* it from a function; you have to use it in the scope it was created, or a nested scope or function call. The restrictions are essentially the same as if you had implemented your algorithm via a tail-recursive function — that is, the function could put each `TestStruct` in a `let` variable and then call itself with the reference to it, to accumulate a set of values that can reference older values.

There are other ways to make a “self-referential” data structure in Rust, such as [`ouroboros`](https://docs.rs/ouroboros/latest/ouroboros/), but as far as I know none of them support making an arbitrary-depth graph that is also movable. If you require the ability to return the structure after creating it, then you should use `Rc` or `Arc`, or an explicit graph data structure such as that provided by [`petgraph`](https://docs.rs/petgraph/).

---

Adding indirection via `Box` does not help permit this sort of reference structure, for two reasons:

1. `Box` implies uniqueness of the pointer to its contents in exactly the same way direct ownership or `&mut` does. As far as the language rules are concerned, moving a `Box<T>` has exactly the same implications for an `&T` as moving the `T` itself does. (`ouroboros` works by creating something `Box`-like that *does not* assert uniqueness in this way.)
2. There's nothing in the borrow checker to perform analysis which proves that *the box isn't dropped until after the references to it are*. For example, suppose `Vec<Box<TestStruct>>` were allowed; this would imply that the `TestStruct`s have to be dropped in reverse order of their position in the vector (otherwise an `impl Drop for TestStruct` could observe an invalid reference). But, there is nothing in `Vec` that says the items can't be reordered, so that would not be sufficient.

   You would need a special data structure that allows only safe operations, and drops in the right order (basically a combination of the ideas from `typed_arena` and `ouroboros`). In principle, such a data structure could exist, but I don't know of one having been written.

Comment: Thanks Kevin! That's helpful, thanks. Added some clarifying notes and a follow-up question to the original post.

Comment: @Simplex Okay, `Box` is worth addressing. I've added a section about that. (Please edit your question to [not contain "edit:" but just say what it has to say as if it were always that way](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127639/when-is-edit-update-appropriate-in-a-post).)

Comment: I posted a related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74166655/222262), as I didn't want to clutter up this question.