# Is is possible to have a mutable container of immutable elements?

Tags: rust, containers, immutability

Below, my `TestStruct` instance is wrapped in two containers: a `Box`, then a `Vec`. From the perspective of a new Rust user it's surprising that moving the `Box` into the `Vec` makes both the `Box` and the `TestStruct` instance mutable.

```rust
struct TestStruct { value: i32 }

fn test_fn() {
    let immutable_instance = TestStruct{value: 123};
    let immutable_box = Box::new(immutable_instance);
    let mut mutable_vector = vec!(immutable_box);

    mutable_vector[0].value = 456;
}
```

Is there a similar construct whereby the boxed value is immutable, but the container of boxes is mutable? More generally, is it possible to have multiple "layers" of containers without the whole tree being either mutable or immutable?

Comment: You could change `Box::new()` to `Rc::new()` and get closer to what you want. `Rc` is a shared container and it prevents mutation of its content. (But even then there are ways to do it if there is only one owner...)

Comment: Mutability in Rust is not a function of the value, but is instead a function of the binding. You can take an "immutable" value and make it mutable again simply by assigning it to a `mut` variable: [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2021&gist=628d42a5774f939dd73be69adb139e09).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is there a similar construct whereby the boxed value is immutable, but the container of boxes is mutable? More generally, is it possible to have multiple "layers" of containers without the whole tree being either mutable or immutable?

Not really. You could easily create one (just create a wrapper object which implements [`Deref`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Deref.html) but not `DerefMut`), but the reality is that Rust doesn't really see (im)mutability that way, because its main concern is controlling sharing / visibility.

After all, for an external observer what difference is there between

```
mutable_vector[0].value = 456;
```

and

```
mutable_vector[0] = Box::new(TestStruct{value: 456});
```

?

None is the answer, because Rust's ownership system means it's not possible for an observer to have kept a handle on the original `TestStruct`, thus they can't know whether that structure was replaced or modified in place<sup>[1]</sup><sup>[2]</sup>.

If you want to secure your internal state, use visibility instead: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=8a9346072b32cedcf2fccc0eeb9f55c5

```rust
mod foo {
    pub struct TestStruct { value: i32 }
    impl TestStruct {
        pub fn new(value: i32) -> Self { Self { value } }
    }
}

fn test_fn() {
    let immutable_instance = foo::TestStruct{value: 123};
    let immutable_box = Box::new(immutable_instance);
    let mut mutable_vector = vec!(immutable_box);

    mutable_vector[0].value = 456;
}
```

does not compile because from the point of view of `test_fn`, `TestStruct::value` is not accessible. Therefore `test_fn` has no way to mutate a `TestStruct` unless you add an `&mut` method on it.

---

[1]: technically they could check the address in memory and that *might* tell them, but even then it's not a sure thing (in either direction) hence [pinning](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/pin/index.html) being a thing.

[2]: this observability distinction is also embraced by other languages, for instance the [Clojure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clojure) language largely falls on the "immutable all the things" side, however it has a concept of *transients* which allow [locally mutable objects](https://clojure.org/reference/transients)